# Getting current client ip address using HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR?

Tags: c#, http, networking, server, ip-address

I need to get current ip address of user who loads the application.I tried using like this.It works but sometimes ,it gets value for HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in this format 2405:204:71c7:d1b5::1e9b:90a5 .I need to get IPV4 address.

```
protected string GetIPAddress()
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        string ipAddress = context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ipAddress))
        {
            string[] addresses = ipAddress.Split(',');
            if (addresses.Length != 0)
            {
                return addresses[0];
            }
        }
        return context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    }
```

Comment: If the user uses ipv6 there is no ipv4 address...

Comment: User have both ipv4 as 157.50.40.142 and ipv6 as 2405:204:71c7:d1b5::1e9b:90a5 .I need ipv4 address.Is there is any way to get it.

Comment: Have a look at the network layer using wireshark or something and find out what information are present in the http request. A user does not have to have a ipv4 address, you should not rely on that.

Comment: Also just assuming a users real ip is reported via the 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' header is rather fatal. I can send you that header with any value i can image and your code would belive that :)

Comment: Your service is clearly *available* to both `IPv4` and `IPv6` clients. You cannot expect to get this information via these means if they've used IPv6 to connect. If you're in a limited environment where all clients will be present in an accessible DNS server for both forward and reverse lookups, that may work.

Comment: Is there is any other way to get the user current ip address

Comment: What is your problem with "REMOTE_ADDR"? Thats the only information that can not be spoofed in the sense that the connection happend from there.

Comment: Every sec remote ip address differs

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Is there is any way to convert ipv6 string to ipv4 string

Comment: @Achu_L - no, outside of some specific uses cases using special address ranges, there's no correlation between ipv6 and ipv4 addresses.